# How can I make R CMD check **not** to check for non-ASCII characters in data?

Tags: r, utf-8, ascii

I am building a package with `UTF-8`. I have put in the `description` file `Encoding: UTF-8` but `R CMD check` still checks for non-ASCII characters in datasets.

Is it possible to make `R CMD check` not to check for non-ASCII characters?

Comment: How are you running check and how are you storing the data?

Comment: @hadley I am running check on Windows' command line with `R CMD check myPackage`. The data are `.rda` files created by the `package.skeleton` function, all of them data frames loaded on the workspace by reading `.csv` files.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @hadley I actually get no error messages; but when we want to do the check it takes a **lot** of time, for almost every single line of data is non-ASCII and check prints every one of them.

Comment: R-exts says "If the DESCRIPTION file is not entirely in ASCII it should contain an ‘Encoding’ field specifying an encoding. This is used as the encoding of the DESCRIPTION file itself and of the R and NAMESPACE files, and as the default encoding of .Rd files.". So specifying the encoding won't help, but I don't see what will - non-ASCII data may not be permitted.

Comment: When I first read I thought that the Encoding was for the package as a whole, I did not notice that it was for everything but '.rda' files... As an alternative, is there a way to make `check` skip this part?

Comment: I don't think so - I'd recommend asking on R-devel.